# Prove that $\mathbb{R}^2 \times S^1 $ and $M=\left\lbrace (x,y,z,w) \in \mathbb{R}^4 \mid x^2+y^2- z^2-w^2 = 1 \right\rbrace$ are diffeomorphic

Tags: differential-geometry, manifolds

Let be $M= \left\lbrace  (x,y,z,w) \in \mathbb{R}^4 \mid x^2+y^2- z^2-w^2 = 1 \right\rbrace$.

I have proved that $M$ is a embedded submanifold of $\mathbb{R}^4 $ of dimension $3$.

I have now to prove that $M$ is diffeomorphic to $\mathbb{R}^2 \times S^1 $.

Can someone give me an hint to find a diffeomorphism?

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**HINT**: Can you write down a diffeomorphism
$$S^1\times\Bbb R\to \{(x,y,z)\in\Bbb R^3: x^2+y^2-z^2=1\}?$$

Comment: Thank you for the help! Is the final diffeomorphism from $S^1 \times \mathbb{R}^2$ to M $(x,y,z,w) \rightarrow  (\sqrt{1+z^2+w^2}x,\sqrt{1+z^2+w^2}y,z,w)$ ?

Comment: And then $S^1 \times \mathbb{R}^2$ is diffeomorphic to $ \mathbb{R}^2 \times S^1$ and I have finished.

Comment: Looks good. Of course, to check that it's a diffeomorphism, you probably need *one* variable parametrizing $S^1$.